# Alphablending not resulting in desired image

Tags: c++, opengl

I grab images from two cameras (each image 8bit grayscale), and upload those images to a texture. I then want to draw those textures overlayed, to result in 50% from one image, and 50% from the other image, but I don't know why it wouldn't result in what I need.

Below is my setup for alpha blending:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);  // Alpha Blending
```

To update my textures:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_INTENSITY, g_Image[g_iCounter].GetCols(), g_Image[g_iCounter].GetRows(), 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, g_Image[g_iCounter].GetData());
```

`g_Image` is a FlyCapture2 Image (Point Grey SDK), `GetCols() / GetRows()` returns the size of the image, `GetData()` the raw data pointer. This works fine, if I want to display the images side by side this does exactly what I want.

My drawing code:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        // Front Face
        glTexCoord2f(left, bottom);     glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  0.5f);
        glTexCoord2f(right, bottom);    glVertex3f( 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.5f);
        glTexCoord2f(right, top);       glVertex3f( 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.5f);
        glTexCoord2f(left, top);        glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  0.5f);
        glEnd();

        if(interleaved)
        {
            top = 0.0f;
            bottom = 1.0f;
            left = 0.0f;
            right = 1.0f;

            glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5);
            switch(flags1)
            {
                case 0: break;
                case 1: left = 1.0f; right = 0.0f; break;
                case 2: top = 1.0f; bottom = 0.0f; break;
                case 3: top = 1.0f; bottom = 0.0f; left = 1.0f; right = 0.0f; break;
                default: break;
            }
            glEnable(GL_BLEND);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            // Front Face
            glTexCoord2f(left, bottom);     glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  0.5f);
            glTexCoord2f(right, bottom);    glVertex3f( 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.5f);
            glTexCoord2f(right, top);       glVertex3f( 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.5f);
            glTexCoord2f(left, top);        glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  0.5f);
            glEnd();
            glDisable(GL_BLEND);
        }
    }
```

This though will always result in me seeing both images, but the first image drawn will always the better visible one, and it's no 50/50 blend. What do I need to alter to get it to do 50/50?

Comment: Side project: If you feel like a bit of fun, another way to alpha blend two textures is to load them both and write a shader to blend them on a single polygon.

Comment: Deprecated code detected.

Comment: Yes, its OpenGL 1.0 I think, but it just needs to display textures, so I didn't bother writing my own shaders. In a worst case scenario, I could just interleave the images manually.

Answer (score 0):

Don't draw them on top of each other.  Move the second slightly closer to the camera, just by a whisker.  A difference of about `0.000001` ought to do it.

Comment: Nope, that did not do it. It had no effect whatsoever unfortunately. But I added undefined behaviour by that, so I fixed the position of the second image to be slightly in front of the first.

Comment: Have you disabled lighting?  If lighting is enabled it can cause blend colours to get watered down.  Or I might have it the wrong way round.  Been quite a while since I did any GL.  Try `glDisable(GL_LIGHTING)`

Comment: Yes, lighting was disabled. I don't understand why the one image is there with like 70% intensity, and the other with around 30% only. I don't grasp whats happening there.

Comment: Hmmm, thinking about it, you probably have the first one with colour `(1,1,1,1)`.  So it's rendered at full brightness.  What you really want is `(0.5,0.5,0.5,1)`, and then overlay with `(1,1,1,0.5)`.  This has the effect of averaging the two images.

Comment: Also, just reading up on `glBlendFunc`, it seems that maybe the way you had your colours set originally would work if you first called `glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`.  Read this: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBlendFunc.xml

Comment: @paddy unless depth buffering is enabled, there's no problem with drawing them at the same positions (in fact, that's what you want if you want pixels to line up under all projection transformations).